# Error while opening excel file with "Data validation" feature

Tags: excel-services

When I open a sharepoint Excel file, the error message is: The workbook cannot be opened because it contains the following features that are not supported by Excel in the browser.

I know this is a normal function of sharepoint, but is there any way make sharepoint not show this message? Thanks in advance.

Comment: does it show the message and let you view teh workbook or does it not let you view it atall?

Answer (score 2):

You can force opening a file with the client application, just modify the advanced library settings:

At the section "Open documents in Browser" select "Open with client application"

Answer (score 0):

As you know Office Web Apps doesn't support this feature "Data validation”.

For you to open the file you can do two things: either open it in Excel 2010 directly, or you can open it in Outlook Web Access (OWA) if you remove the data validation but you would need to open the file in excel first!

I dont think you can stop the error message from appearing. I could be wrong but I would think you couldnt stop the error message from appearing.

Answer (score 0):

Try it out in IE7 or above. Some times it matters which version of IE we are using to view office documents in SharePoint. Same problem may repeat in older IE versions also...

Answer (score 0):

Try the blog : I am unable to copy the content 
http://sharepointknowledgebase.blogspot.com/2013/08/the-workbook-cannot-be-opened-error.html

Answer (score 0):

Try MS Office repair. Ensure all office items and IE are closed while running the repair. Reboot the computer once completed.